# bower_components created at wrong directory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Using Windows 7, Webstorm 10.0.1, current node.js, npm, bower, etc.

I created the default Webstorm AngularJS project, did not change anything and clicked "Run index.html". The page loaded but Angular was not running. From the source I saw that the files were missing `<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>`. The directory `bower_components` was missing. Then I searched for it and it was created at `C:\Users\<username>\bower_components` whereas my Webstorm projects are under `C:\Users\<username>\WebstormProjects\angularjs`.

What configurations need to be changed to make my AngularJS app work?

Additional info:

`.bowerrc`

```
{
  "directory": "app/bower_components"
}
```

`bower.json`

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.x",
    "angular-route": "1.2.x",
    "angular-loader": "1.2.x",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2.x",
    "html5-boilerplate": "~4.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be you are missing to install dependencies here.

In your project you have a `bower.json` file present. Go to that directory and run `bower install` command. This command will install all the specified dependencies of your project which is mentioned in bower.json

Comment: Yes executing the command made it work. Why does "Run" not trigger this command?

Comment: Which IDE you are using?

Comment: As stated I am using Webstorm

Comment: Yup, Run command only make that directory live so default request will go on index.html. Here this command is for environment setup and it varies as per project structure and tools used in that. So Run is totally independent from this all.

Comment: @Indianer If your project is configured with the build tool then it may have configured commands to do all together.Hope my answer help you. Please accept if it so.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit `.bowerrc` in the root of your project folder and set the directory you want to use:

```
{
  "directory" : "public/bower_components"
}
```

More info in [Bower docs](http://bower.io/docs/config/)